# Double Object Nesting JSON Response Body [Objective C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

In Objective C how should I write a Double Nested Response Body along the form:

```
{'ms_request':
         {'user':
             {'api_key':'',
              'username':'',
              'password':''
             }
         }
 }
```

---

I know how to do it for one object, but double nesting the objects has me stumped.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 NSArray *loginDetails = [self authenticationHelper];

NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     [loginDetails objectAtIndex:0], @"password",
                     [loginDetails objectAtIndex:1], @"username",
                     [loginDetails objectAtIndex:2], @"api_key",
                     nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:autheticationURL]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
[request setHTTPBody:postdata];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `NSDictionary` [literals](http://cocoaheads.tumblr.com/post/17757846453/objective-c-literals-for-nsdictionary-nsarray). Something like this (just make sure that you check all the values to avoid insertion of `nil` objects):

```
NSDictionary *reqDict = 
@{@"ms_request":
         @{@"user":
             @{@"api_key":loginDetails[2],
              @"username":loginDetails[1],
              @"password":loginDetails[0]
             }
         }
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add dictionary in another dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 [loginDetails objectAtIndex:0], @"password",
                 [loginDetails objectAtIndex:1], @"username",
                 [loginDetails objectAtIndex:2], @"api_key",
                 nil];

NSDictionary *userDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 tmp, @"user"];

NSDictionary *requestDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 userDict, @"ms_request"];

NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDict options:0 error:&error];
```

PS: In JSON, **{ }** represents dictionary and **[ ]** represents array.

Comment: Woo nice one! You need to nil terminate the dictionaries but that worked thanks!